# Web applications for natural maths calculations

Tags: web-apps, math, calculator

[Soulver](http://www.acqualia.com/soulver/) is a Mac application that allows users to enter maths and text together to solve various problems. Is there a web application that allows similar functionality?

Features:

- Web application
- Natural language interface
- Should handle basic operations such as addition, multiplication, percents, unit conversion
- Unit conversion would be nice

Comment: like http://www.wolframalpha.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn’t feel and look like Soulver (at least according to its introduction video), but [InstaCalc](http://instacalc.com/) seems to be something similar.

You can name and share calculations (even without login): http://instacalc.com/26664

It’s row-based, and you can reference the results from rows in other rows.

[image: InstaCalc screenshot of example calculation]

[Natural language](http://instacalc.com/10246) can be used like `15 million`, `10m`, and `3k`, but it doesn’t support "four" or "one million".

It supports [unit conversion](http://instacalc.com/1736), e.g.:

- `1 foot in cm` = 30.48 cm
- `1 foot/sec in cm/hour` = 109,728 cm/hour
- `15 apples/day in hours per apple` = 1.6 hours / apple
- `1 USD in EUR` = 0.7848 EUR
- `1 hour in days` = 0.04166666667 days

It has some functions useful [for programmers](http://instacalc.com/1739), and it even supports `if`, and can output strings depending on calculations, [e.g.](http://instacalc.com/1735):

```
if (BMI < 18.5 ) {diagnosis = "underweight"} else if (BMI < 24.9){"normal weight"} else if (BMI < 29.9){diagnosis ="overweight"} else {diagnosis ="obese"}
```